# Can you use gulp to concatenate files together based on their parent folder?

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

I am trying to set up a generic frame for me to use for multiple projects. I am mostly trying to do this to get experience with gulp/npm and building projects.

I would like to keep all distinct components separated and have gulp tasks to compile each component-folders files together

Specifically, for example...

I would like to use these globs

```
app/components/**/scripts/**/*.js
app/components/**/*.css
```

With these files

```
app/components/about/file1.css
app/components/about/file2.css
app/components/about/scripts/file1.js
app/components/about/scripts/file1.js
app/components/home/file1.css
app/components/home/file2.css
app/components/home/scripts/file1.js
app/components/home/scripts/file1.js
```

and I would like to combine them into these files

```
app/components/about/scripts.js
app/components/home/scripts.js
app/assets/css/components/about_styles.css
app/assets/css/components/home_styles.css
```

I had found [this recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-task-steps-per-folder.md) that looks like it does what I want but it seems very clunky.

Is this possible with gulp? If not is there some module I can use to do this with gulp?

Comment: To me it sounds that you are making your own (very limited) webpack-like tool. Are you aware of this tool? With webpack you can simply require (both scripts and css files) from the browser; whether those files are compiled together and served in one chunk or served individually is configurable.

Comment: No, I have not heard of that. I am really new to anything automated really which is why I am doing this.

Comment: in such a case, you might be interested in Este starter kit: https://github.com/este/este, it's a nice start for your app (it uses webpack for comiling and serving the scripts & styles).

Comment: I will definitely check that out but I honestly wanted to try to do as much myself as possible. I want to really understand what is happening and adding too much at once usually overwhelms me.

Comment: Well, the thing is, you usually want to do much more than just concat the files; typically you want to compile the sources to es5 syntax, minify, watch files suring development, maybe even do some type-checking in development . I would definitely advise you to play with things and understand individual steps of this process, but for more real use-case I'd definitely go for webpack.

Comment: I already have an understanding of all of those. I have used uglifyjs, gulp-tsc, gulp-rename, and a handful of other modules(?) to move files around, compile, and minify them.

Comment: What do you find "clunky" about the recipe you linked to?

Comment: I guess I don't have a very good answer to that. I didn't like that it got folders manually, I assumed there would be a way to do what I wanted with one glob. It looks like it makes a lot of calls to the filesystem, one for every folder to get subfolders and another for each folders subfolders files. Map also makes me a little uneasy because I don't completely understand it.

Comment: Map takes all items in a collection and performs a function against each one of them. It says right at the bottom of the recipe: `folders.map - executes the function once per folder, and returns the async stream`. Also, it's doing what you want asynchronously, which is going to finish a lot faster than another method. Honestly, that recipe seems to be a nice solution to your problem.

Comment: @JTitus thanks for explaining. Why is it called map? I picture like mapping keybindings or something. Either way I guess I will just use that solution. Either that or webpack...?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use [gulp-concat](https://github.com/contra/gulp-concat)

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('aboutScripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('./app/components/about/scripts/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/components/about/'));
});

gulp.task('homeScripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('./app/components/home/scripts/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/components/home/'));
});
```

etc.

and possibly also [gulp-concat-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat-css)

Comment: I saw this but I wanted to be able to support any number of subfolders, I don't want to hard-code the folders names.